# FullCalendar user-defined number of days per week

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Our customer would like our app to have a per-user setting that allows each user to decide the number of days they see in the "week" view of FullCalendar.

Most want to see 10 days (instead of 7). Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give some additional details like what calendar you have used and give if you have any example..

Comment: This question is specifically about how to customize the component named "FullCalendar" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)